# SyntaxError: invalid character '‘' (U+2018)g

Tags: python, chatgpt

ChatGPT 3 を使いたいんですけどなぜかエラーが出て使えません。
初心者で分からないことも多いのでかみ砕いて説明していただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いします。

```
>>> import os
>>>
>>> import openai
>>> openai.api_key = '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'
>>> prompt = ‘Hi! How are you today?’
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    prompt = ‘Hi! How are you today?’
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid character '‘' (U+2018)g
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 主にWeb上の記事からコピペしたりすると勝手に半角の記号文字が全角の類似の記号文字に変換されてしまう現象が発生する場合があります。必ず発生する訳でも無いのでコピペには注意しましょう。あるいは自分で誤解して全角を入力していたり、全角半角の入力/変換モードを間違えているとかもあり得ます。

Answer (score 3):

引用符の記号が違います。シングルクォーテーションは (日本語配列なら) <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd> で入力してみてください。

参考:
[引用符 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BC%95%E7%94%A8%E7%AC%A6)

プログラミングでは "直線形" の記号を使用します。`"`, `'`