# SyntaxError: invalid character '“' (U+201C) につきまして

Tags: python

検索しても改善の事例を見つけることができず、もしご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

下記を参照してGoogle ColabにWhisperをインストールし動画を文字おこししたいなと思っております。

https://aismiley.co.jp/ai_news/what-is-whisper/

以下のコードを入力して実行したところ、エラーが出てまいりました。
コードのどの部分を直せばよいでしょうか？

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
SyntaxError: invalid character '“' (U+201C)
```

**入力したコード:**

```
model = whisper.load_model(“base”)
result = model.transcribe(“sankaku.mp4”)
print(result[“text”])
```

Comment: 「”」を「"」にしたら処理が進みましたが、長文のエラーが出てまいりました。。

Comment: 参考記事
https://errorsingo.com/compilation-invalid-identifier-u201c/

Comment: 状況が変わって質問内容が解決し、別の問題になったのなら、この質問は自己回答で解決とし新規に質問を起こすか、タイトルを含めて新しい問題の内容に全面的に書き変えてみてください。「長文のエラーが出てまいりました。」とコメントするだけでは何も助言・回答するための情報がありません。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問内容をブラッシュアップしてみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [スクショしたコードで質問して良いですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3765)

Comment: ちなみに元の質問内容に関しては、文字は違うけれども内容としてはこちらの記事と同様のものでしょう。[SyntaxError: invalid character '‘' (U+2018)g](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/94659/26370)

Comment: 「長文のエラーが出てまいりました。。」とのことですが、どの行でどのようなエラーが発生したのでしょうか？エラーメッセージを省略しないで（ユーザー名等は隠していただいて結構です）掲載してください。

Comment: mp4の変換に対応していないようでした。mp3やwavについては、問題なく変更できました。ファイル形式の問題でした。

Answer (score 1):

> SyntaxError: invalid character '“' (U+201C)

ってのははやいはなし、コード中では使用することができない文字を使っている、ってことです
いわゆる、全角文字はコード中には使用できません

Answer (score 0):

私も同じところでつまづきました。ダブルクォーテーション全角「”」みたいだったので半角「"」に変更したら成功しましたよ!